# Mock a function imported in different ways

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to mock a function in a module while testing, here is an example:

```
# module.py

def func1(x, y):
    return x + y


# main.py

import module
def run(a):
    x, y = a
    return module.func1(x, y)


# test.py

import unittest
import mock
import main


def func_to_replace(x, y):
    return x * y


class TestClassMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('module.func1', side_effect=func_to_replace)
    def test_method(self, func):
        self.assertEqual(main.run([3, 4]), 12)


unittest.main()
```

There is a function in module.py that is called in main.py, and I want to test it replacing `func1` with another function `func_to_replace`.

This code works fine, but if I replace the invocation

```
# main.py

import module
...
module.func1(x, y)
```

with this

```
# main.py

from module import func1
...
func1(x, y)
```

it does not work, because the function `module.func1` can not be found.

I would like to mock a function `func1` even if I don't know the way how it is imported and invoked. How can I do that?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6) section of the documentation.

I believe you need to patch `"main.func1"` if you do `from module import func1` inside `main.py`.

Comment: It is clear, so depending on how I imported the function I mock it in different ways. (I mock either module.func1 or main.func1), but the question was how can I mock it regardless of the way of invocation.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I don't think you can do that. But maybe my mocking skills are just lacking :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. You'd patch the module and then mock the function on the patched module.

So it'd look like this:

```
# test.py

import unittest
import mock
import main


def func_to_replace(x, y):
    return x * y


class TestClassMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('main.module')
    def test_method(self, module_mock):
        module_mock.func1 = func_to_replace
        self.assertEqual(main.run([3, 4]), 12)
```